# How can I prevent validation schema regeneration on each keystroke

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, formik, yup

I am using `Formik`'s `useFormik()` to keep track of my form state and `Yup` for validation. Some of my form fields are interdependant. In my use case, I need to dynamically generate the validation schema. Here are relevent parts of my code:

```
// main view where I create formik and validation schema

const EntityView = (props) => {
    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            properties: [
                // ... array of objects describing form fields
                //     and validation patterns
            ]
            // ...
        },

        onSubmit: () => { },
        // notice! dynamically generated schema
        validationSchema: generateFormikValidationSchema(allEntityProperties),
        validateOnChange: true,
    })

    return (
        <div className="space-y-20">
            {formik.values.properties.map(property => {
                switch (property.type) {
                    case "number":
                        return <Input name={property.name}
                                      value={/* assosiated formik value*/}
                                      onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                      ...
                                    />
                    
                    case "textarea":
                        return <Textarea name={property.name}
                                         value={/* assosiated formik value*/}
                                         onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                         ...
                      />
                }
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is how I dynamically generate validation schema:

```
const generateFormikValidationSchema = properties => {
  console.log(" regenerating ...") // ! <---------- HERE
  const shape = {}

  properties.forEach(prop => {
    if (prop.details.is_required) {
      switch (prop.details.type) {
        case "number":
          shape[prop.id] = yup.number()
            .min(1, "must be greater than 1")
            .max(49, "must be less than 50")
            .required("majburiy maydon")
            .when(["a"], (reliantProp, schema) => {
              let newRule = undefined
              
              // code emitted for simplicity
              switch (otherFieldValue) {
                ...
              }
              return newRule
            })
          break
        case "textarea":
          ...
      }
    }
  })

  return yup.object().shape({ properties: yup.object(shape) })
}
```

As you can see I create a formik instance once and pass formik's value and handler functions down to child components.

Everyting works fine (including interdependent validation, formik's state). My problem is on each keystroke my validation schema gets re-generated (`generateFormikValidationSchema` is called). I want it to be genereted only on the first page load. I researched SO for solution but could not find an answer that fits my case.

How can I solve this problem? Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 1):

Use the `useMemo` hook to get the memoized value of the validation schema.

```
const memoizedValidationSchema = useMemo(
  () => generateFormikValidationSchema(allEntityProperties),
  [allEntityProperties]
);
```

This will guarantee that the validation schema is updated only when the `allEntityProperties` are updated.

Pass this as the validation schema to your form.

```
const formik = useFormik({
  // Other properties
  validationSchema: memoizedValidationSchema,
});
```

It is possible that `allEntityProperties` itself is an array whose reference updates on every render. This will make the `useMemo` hook useless and still generate a fresh validation schema on every render. You can try workarounds using refs in those cases.

Comment: Thanks. You gave a clear direction to me. After a bit research, I used your suggestion and just gave an empty dependency array. Now it works as expected. PS. I used `// eslint-disable-next-line` to disable console warnings